# How to get path from one node to all other nodes in a weighted tree in minimum time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, computer-science

I just want to get the distance of source node from every node. But it is different than graph problems since it is a tree and path between every node is unique so I expect answer to be in more efficient time.
Is it possible to get answer in efficient time?

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right that in a tree, the difficulty of finding a path between two nodes is a lot lower than in a general graph because once you find *any* path (at least, one without cycles) you know it's the shortest. So all you have to do is just find all paths starting at the given node and going to each other node. You can do this with either a depth-first or a breadth-first search in time O(n). To find the lengths, just keep track of the lengths of the edges you've seen along the paths you've traveled as you travel them.

Answer (score -1):

This is *not* different from "graph problems": a tree is a special case of a graph.  [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) is a standard of graph traversal.  Just modify it a little: keep all of the path lengths as you find them, and don't worry about the compare-update step, since you're going to keep all of the results.  Continue until you run out of nodes to check, and there are your path lengths.

Comment: While you're absolutely right that a tree is a special case of a graph, algorithms that are designed to work on general graphs might be slower than equivalent algorithms designed to work on trees because they have to watch out for cases that otherwise can't arise. You could run Dijkstra's algorithm here, but the priority queue is overkill because you'll never find competing paths to a given node.

Comment: Hence my hint to modify the algorithm.